# Confusion over formula for finding V during SVD

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I understand any rectangular mxn matrix A is a factorization of the form:
$$ A = U\Sigma V^{\top}$$
where U and V are orthogonal matrices and $\Sigma$ is diagonal.
Say, I have found U and $\Sigma$ and looking for V. I have been told the following
$$
v_i = \frac{(A^{\top}U)_i}{\sigma_i}
$$
where 0 $\leq$ i $\leq$ p and p = min(m,n)
The remaining vectors in V can then be calculated by the cross product of these vectors.
When using this formula, it seems to be correct however I am unsure why. The proof I was given is as follows
$$
A = U\Sigma V^{\top} \\ 
A^{\top}A = A^{\top}U\Sigma V^{\top} \\ 
I = A^{\top}U\Sigma V^{\top} \\
A^{\top}U = V\Sigma^{\top} \\
(A^{\top}U)_i = v_i\sigma_i \\
v_i = \frac{(A^{\top}U)_i}{\sigma_i}
$$
However, this would only hold if A is an orthogonal matrix which is not the case in the problems I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true because $A^\top U=(U\Sigma V^\top)^\top U=(V\Sigma^\top U^\top)U=V\Sigma^\top$.